# Loading values from the memory in MIPS doesn't work correctly

Tags: arrays, memory, mips

Greedings,
I am working on an MIPS project in Mars. Sadly it looks like, I don't understand correctly how MIPS works.
For example: I have the Register $a0 with the baseaddress of an array and in register $a1 is the length of the array.
Every element in the array is a halfword. I want to shift a element one postion if the number before is a zero. E.g. 2 0 2 0 4 => 2 2 0 4 0
The problem is, that my program doesn't even load the right Elements from the array.

```
.text
.global move_one

move_one:
 addiu $sp $sp -12
 sw    $a0 8($sp)
 sw    $a1 4($sp)
 sw    $a2 0($sp)
 li    $v0 0
 b     loop

loop:
 addiu $a1 $a1 -1
 beqz  $a1 end
 lhu   $a2 0($a0)
 addiu $a0 $a0 2
 beqz  $a2 shift
 b     loop

shift:
 lhu   $a2 0($a0)
 sh    $a2 -2($a0)
 sh    $zero 0($a0)
 li    $v0 1
 b     loop

end:
 lw    $a0 8($sp)
 lw    $a1 4($ap)
 lw    $a2 0($ap)
 addiu $sp $sp 12
 jr    $ra
```

With my tests I found out, that shift never get called and $a2 have different values over the runningtime, also 0.

I hope I could make my problem clear.

I am really thankful for any help.

Edit:

```
    .data
    .globl main

message:
    .asciiz "move_one returned: "

board:
    .half 0,0,2,0
    .half 0,0,0,0
    .half 0,0,0,0
    .half 0,0,0,0

buf:
    .word 0,0,0,0

    
    .text

main:
    la $t0 board
    la $t1 buf

    sw $t0 0($t1)
    addiu $t0 $t0 2
    sw $t0 4($t1)
    addiu $t0 $t0 2
    sw $t0 8($t1)
    addiu $t0 $t0 2
    sw $t0 12($t1)


    la $a0 buf
    la $a1 4
    jal move_one
    
    move $t0 $v0
    la $a0 message
    li $v0 4
    syscall
    move $a0 $t0
    li $v0 1
    syscall
    li $v0 11
    li $a0 10
    syscall

    li $a1 16
    la $a0 board
    jal print_board_test
    li  $v0 10
    syscall
```

Comment: Hard to reason over this snippet.  Suggest to show your whole program, including data and `main`.

Comment: Sure, I will give the test I am using:

Comment: You're passing `buf` to `move_one` in `$a0`: don't you want to pass `board` instead?  I also don't understand the intent of your setup code, storing addresses/pointers into memory at `buf`.  There's definitely a mismatch between what is being passed and what is expected.

Comment: I really don't get it either, that it pass buf. Could it maybe because that it just want to test the first row or something? I must not change anythink in this test main. This have to work.

Comment: What do you mean, it stores addresses in buff? As I interpret it, it stores the values in bord at the address of buf.

Comment: Now I have understand the problem. $a0 stores the address of the address, for the purpose that we can shift the numbers better up and down. 

Thanks for you help